# Another missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql and I have this problem with trigger, that should just take value from the sequence. If I understood correctly, (tried few examples) in case like this you don't need clause FROM (like in ORACLE you would add 'from dual').

Trigger looks something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_fct_name_id_autoinc()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT "NAME_ID_SEQ".NEXTVAL INTO NEW."ID" ;
RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Of course, I've done something wrong. Error I get is:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "NAME_ID_SEQ" Where: PL/pgSQL function trigger_fct_name_id_autoinc() line 3 at SQL statement

Tried to find some answers in the web, but either there was none, or I don't understand postgresql well enough to understand what people write. In most topics the answer involves aliases, but I don't think that's the case here.

Should I somehow add FROM clause, or is it just a sign of a different issue?

Comment: You are using Oracle syntax to access a sequence. This is not how it works in Postgres. Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html#AEN72475 and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: Plus you don't need the trigger at all. You can use a sequence as a default value for a column, or even easier use a `serial`. Again this is documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Oracle syntax to get the next value from your sequence. Use the Postgres' [`nextval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html):

```
SELECT nextval('NAME_ID_SEQ') INTO NEW."ID" ;
```

Comment: Ah, had no idea it works like that in Postgres. Code was coverted with ora2pg from Oracle and I assumed nexvtal is used porperly. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Sorry for asking another (probably dumb) question, but is there any system table where I can find whole db code? I would like to change nextval thing in all trigers and wherever else this issue ocurrs, but I can't seem to find table containing trigger definitions neither in `information_schema` nor in `pg_catalog`

Comment: @Hisu: I don't know. I do for Oracle, but not for PG.

Comment: Just for info, if anyone would be looking for this in the future. I haven't found such table in postgres (maybe there isn't one?). In the end I've used command 'pg_dump -U username --schema-only dbname -f textfile.sql' on linux terminal. It gices dump in text, to recreate whole database. --schema-only flag ignores data (I wanted only definitions) and -f savs it to the file (if there's no directory it's saved to the place you are at). You get everything  - tables, sequences, triggers, functions etc, but they're segregated, so if you want like me all definitions of one kind it's easy to sort.

Comment: From that just edit with mass ctrl+f and replace. At least that's what I did, haven't found any better way.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments but just wanted to leave here another info for someone looking for it - I've used pg_dump, but it seems there is system table called `pg_catalog.pg_proc` where you can find and edit sources of all functions.

Comment: @Hisu: You might consider creating a new question and self-answer it with this information.

Comment: There is another question from me, just wanted to leave it here to make looking for it easier